# WPF Grid not keeping its Width and Height

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Canvas inside of a Grid in a WPF app. I want to draw a skeleton in Canvas from Kinect data. But the Canvas has a tiny width, probably 1px. The Grid makes it shrink, not keeping its set Width and Height. How to make Grid keep its declared size?

Comment: Why don't you post the relevant XAML?

Comment: Is the Canvas inside a grid with a row/col definition width or height set to Auto?

Comment: This question is really unclear. It needs the XAML posted so people can understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both the grid and the canvas have `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` and `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"`